# Все ли определения однородны?

Tags: однородные-члены

"НО затем ты пошла и осквернила нашу воду своим вонючим, распутным (,) нагим телом. Нагим!" (к/ф "Колония Дигнидад").

Однородны ли определения "распутным" и "нагим" или между ними другие отношения? Если руководствоваться интонацией, то запятая не нужна.

Comment: Татьяна, на сайте принято не только принимать ответ галочкой, но и отмечать его стрелочкой вверх (также это касается всех полезных ответов и вопросов). // На мой вопрос в комментариях Вы почему-то так и не ответили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Но затем ты пошла и осквернила нашу воду **своим вонючим, распутным нагим** телом. Нагим!*

Нагое (обнаженное) тело — это относительное прилагательное, отнесенное к существительному.

Однородный ряд определений: ***вонючий, распутный***. Значение сближенные (обобщенный образ, общее восприятие).

Интонация: *Но затем ты пошла и осквернила нашу вОду / своим **вонЮчим, / распутным** нагим тЕлом.*

**Перечисление** при произношении двух определений.